# Como resolver error: Cant no resolved for configuration en Android Studio 2021.1.1

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

No entiendo nada de este programa y pasé de poder crear mi App a este problema:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

*Cabe aclarar que ya probé lo del botón del grade pero tampoco funciona*

Este es el Gradle:

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }    
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné: quizá sea una animalada lo que hice, pero lo pongo por si le sirve a alguien. Después de probar todo lo que encontré y que nada funcionara, lo que hice fue:
-Crear un nuevo proyecto.
-Modificar todos los archivos gradle del proyecto que tenía el problema hasta dejarlos igual a los del nuevo proyecto.
-Sincronizar.
-comentar todas las importaciones que marcaban error en cada activity
(import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity...(y otras que tenían que ver con kotlin))
-importar lo que me pedía importar.
-la "magia" de kotlin de señalar los objetos de los xml se perdió, así que creé las variables correspondientes y use el mismo findViewById que usaba en java.

Funcionó.